# Swiper does not resize image properly when sidebar is visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use Swiper slider on my webpage. I have sidebar there, but when I display page on screen resolution 1680x1050 (both sidebar+webpage are visible) Swiper image is not resized correctly - image is cut off. But, when I hide the sidebar, whole slide is displayed correctly.

Here, demo for reference: http://demo.empresario.sk/

There is section with the Swiper slider, and the second section with image and text, where resizing works fine - exactly what i want to achieve with swiper.

I tried couple of settings in main.css file but no luck.
Could someone help me with that issue please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the guideline before asking your question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please provide code snippets or fiddle.

Comment: I tried to upload all the stuff to jsfiddle, but I was not able to upload all the related js files and css files there. Are you able to reach URL: http://demo.empresario.sk/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand but the only way I can see cutted image is when I open website by typing: http://demo.empresario.sk/ in address

but when I refresh the page the image isn't cutted of. I assume it has something with your `ready/load events`, the way you initialize Swiper. We dont have your javascript so we don't know whats happening there...

**I discovered something more...**
When I hit address it seems it initializes Swiper before menu is opened and thats why Swiper is using 100% of window width.

The other way around is that when I hit refresh, image is not cutted of because is using `window.width - menu.width` but when I click menu, slider shows part of next slide. So its opposite, Swiper was initialized after menu is opened.

I think to fix that you would have to reinitialize Swiper everytime you open/close menu... like you do as I assume when you resize window ? Or Swiper actually is doing it for you when you resize window ?

**UPDATE**

I would try to move initialization to your javascript file and whenever window is resized or menu is closed or opened I would call `mySwiper.updateSize()`. Maybe it will do the trick

**Update 2**

at the and 
`mySwiper.update()` did trick instead `mySwiper.updateSize()`

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like you described. When swiper is initialized after sidebar, then swiper looks OK, but slider shows part of next slide - I changed the demo this way.
Are you able to take a look at related js and css via "View source code" option in your browser? If not, I can upload whole content somewhere...

Comment: @ljex I inspected main.js but I coudnt find any of swiper initialization... I found in docs of Swiper something like `mySwiper.updateSize()`, which updates container width. How do you initialize swiper ?

Comment: It is at the end of index file:
...var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {....

Comment: I would try to move initialization to your javascript file and whenever window is `resized` or menu is `closed` or `opened` I would call `mySwiper.updateSize()`. Maybe it will do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot @sonic! It works now. The only thing is, that I had to use setTimeout function to call update, otherwise it did not work.
setTimeout(function () {
                    swiper.update();
                  }, 300);

Comment: @ljex im happy that it worked for you. If you used `jquery scroll event` I think its natural that it fires just after you resize window. try testing it... you need to watch out with it ! Try to console log how many times this update happen. just make `var i = 0` before scroll event and `setTimeout(function () { console.log(i++); swiper.update(); }, 300);` otherwise it may happen that you reinitialize it few times at one scroll ! Please accept my answer if its not the problem. I will gain points :D

Comment: updateSize() did not work for me at all.
Regarding to console.log, I can see call every time when I click to show or close sidebar, but here I'm not sure if I implemented that part (var i = 0 before scroll event ) where you meant.

Comment: @ljex oh so `swiper.update()` worked, ok. I mean if you use `swiper.update()` in your `scroll event` then it could fire multiple times. if you dont use it there then no worries. When I checked your website I saw that when I resize window, your slides dynamicly change width and I didn't know what caused it, your code or `swiper library` itself.

Comment: Actually, I call swiper.update() twice. The first time whenever the window is resized, and second time when sidebar is opened or closed. All is part of main.js script so it is not done by swiper library.

Comment: And when window is resized, are you sure your update happens once there?

Comment: I removed few lines, so hopefully now when window is resized update should be done once only :)

Comment: @ljex I feel like I didn't explain my concern enought. I made fiddle for you to picture what I meant with scroll event: https://jsfiddle.net/b12357jL/

Comment: But I counted the same before. I mean, everytime when I resize the window, count increased by 1, the same output like you have in your fiddle.

Comment: Ok, So How did you figure it out to make only one call? Do you unbind and bind setTimeout?

Comment: I just called setTimeout and then clearTimeout method for swiper. For regular images, resizing is done purely via css.

Answer (score 0):

Was the same issue. And find answer with React Hooks. Hope help some one.

Import swiper

```
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";
```

Init swiper instance with useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    swiper = new SwiperCore(".swiper-container", {
      spaceBetween: 0,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      updateOnWindowResize: true,
      loop: true,
      speed: 1200,
      pagination: {
        clickable: true,
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
      },
      autoplay: {
        delay: 4500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
    });
  }, []);
```

**And one more useEffect . Who observe sidebar show. showLeftSideBar - boolean param, which change by state**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (swiper !== null) {
      swiper.update();
    }
  }, [showLeftSideBar]);
```

Code of my component with material UI

```
<Box className={"swiper-container"}>
  <Box className={"swiper-wrapper"}>
      <SwiperSlide className={"swiper-slide"}>
        <Box>1</Box>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide className={"swiper-slide"}>
        <Box>2</Box>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide className={"swiper-slide"}>
        <Box>3</Box>
      </SwiperSlide>
  </Box>
  <Box className={"swiper-button-next"}>
    <ChevronRightIcon />
  </Box>

  <Box className={"swiper-button-prev"}>
    <ChevronLeftIcon />
  </Box>

  <Box className={"swiper-pagination"}></Box>
</Box>
```

**That's help with this issue**